# Tailwind not working when components are shared through webpack module federation

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, micro-frontend

So I am trying micro fronend and it is working great. The only problem is when the components are shared, the tailwind classes are not working.

Let's say I have App1 which will act like as a remote. I want to share a component.

```
import React from "react";

type PrimaryButtonType = {
  handleOnClick: () => void;
};
export default function PrimaryButton({ handleOnClick }: PrimaryButtonType) {
  return (
    <div className="space-y-5 bg-blue-200" onClick={handleOnClick}>
      Click Me
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the webpack.config.js for the App1.

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = (_, argv) => ({
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3500/",
    clean: true,
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 3500,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: "javascript/auto",
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "remote",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {
        client: "client@http://localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      exposes: {
        "./PrimaryButton": "./src/Component/PrimaryButton.tsx",
        
        
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
});
```

and the host app receive the component as follow

```
const PrimaryButton = lazy(() => import("remote/PrimaryButton"));
```

When I render the component from host, it is working fine. But tailwind classes are not applied. When I inspect the page, I can see tailwind classes are included, but not their relative css classes.

Here is host webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
});
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/entry.ts",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "index_bundle.js",
    publicPath: "http://localhost:5000/",
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"),
    },
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 5000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    // static: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["ts-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    htmlPlugin,

    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "EApplication",
      filename: "engineer.remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {
      
        remote: "remote@http://localhost:3500/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      exposes: {},
      shared: {
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react"],
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
        "react-router-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-router-dom"],
        },
        "react-redux": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-redux"],
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

How can I fix this. I am very new to micro frontend and webpack.

Comment: I just found the error. I have to import "index.css" to the component.

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind can't be shared because of the way that mounts the CSS. It reads all classes on files and generates a style tag only with CSS used. Then, the style from other modules shared with module federation isn't read by tailwind from host mfe.

Here is a topic talking about it https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/discussions/714

There is an idea to get around this in the thread using `mini-css-extract-plugin`

I was with the same problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: can tailwind effects performance if we load full config on root mfe.

Comment: I was thinking about it. I didn't try it. But I solved my problem using mini-css-extract-plugin + css-loader + postcss-loader on webpack config, then it created one css file that I exposed on _next/static/chunks/[name].css and called it on root mfe. It can't be the best way but it solve.